# JavaFX Multiple screens with Menubar on top

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am very new to JavaFX. As I am a swing developer, I am facing some problems with JavaFX. In swing I create a main window with JFrame. On the top I add a Menubar. When a menu item is clicked, a JInternalFrame is opened below the Menubar in a JDesktopPane. I've found this way very useful, because I can open any JInternalFrame from menubar as well as from the JInternalFrame itself. The JInternalFrame remains open until user closes them. When user presses escape button he can go back to the previously opened frame.

I've found some libraries that switch scenes. But I cannot find an equivalent way in JavaFX. Can anyone help me to achieve this ?

Comment: There is no equivalent to "internal frames" in the standard JavaFX libraries, and "Multiple document interfaces" such as that are [considered bad user interface design](http://pixelcentric.net/article-art=docs.html) in general. Consider using a tab pane instead, so your menu adds new tabs to the tab pane, or creating new stand-alone stages. If you really want and MDI you will need to implement the internal windows yourself, or find a third-party library that does so.